# How to test DocuSign Rest API in SOAPUI Tool

Tags: docusignapi

Actually I am trying to test rest API's in SOAPUI tool but I am getting errors.

below is the Rest API Request details;

API Account ID - XXXXXXX
Envelope ID - YYYYYYYY

But I don't know where we can add DocuSign Credential details for Rest API in SOAPUI.

Please refer the below screen shot and also provide some screen shot for learning DocuSign Rest API integration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKoP1.png)

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the SOAPUI page then is an option to enter `Header` details, so enter Authentication related header info in that section, please find below snapshot for your reference:
[image]

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks a lot. I have entered UserName, Password & IntegratorKey details in the header but still same issue. the issue is {
   "errorCode": "AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN",
   "message": "The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed."
}. Could you please explain bit detail for me because I am new to Rest API. Actually I have done SOAP web services integration to JDE successfully with your help.

Comment: Are you setting header Key as `X-DocuSign-Authentication` and its value as `{"Username": "YourUsername", "Password":"YourPassword", "IntegratorKey":"YourIntegratorKey"}`, now as DS Docs you should not use LegacyHeader Authentication, instead use OAUTH2, you can find more details at [REST API Authentication Overview](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication)